# Wireless screen sharing between desktop and tablets

Tags: wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, mirroring

I have a TV/monitor hooked up to my desktop PC running Windows 10. I would like to have two touchscreen tablets for clients to use that would allow them to interact with that monitor that’s hooked up to my desktop PC. It’s more than simply the tablets “mirroring” the monitor/PC, because I want the communication to be BOTH ways, and not just a simple duplication. Does anyone have any idea as to how I can make this happen???
Thank you in advance. Rick

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://www.prijector.com/articles/wireless_screen_sharing.html

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to solve this task is to use **[Spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/)** app.

https://spacedesk.net/##box_430

Server app part - on PC,
Client/viewer app part - on tablets/PC (up to 4 devices)